# error in insert into statement aspx

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

this is my code for insert satement but aspx throwing error is error in insert into statement

the all code block goes properly but i didnt understand how the code is not working for insert data here is the code with all parameters and their respective values, the code thrown error for the excution on query

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class userLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\abhishek\\Downloads\\startbootstrap-sb-admin-gh-pages\\startbootstrap-sb-admin-gh-pages\\crm1.mdb");
    }
    //Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="E:\study\ty bca\Wheeler Dealer\App_Data\Register.mdb";Persist Security Info=True
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbParameter p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
        p1 = new OleDbParameter();
        p2 = new OleDbParameter();
        p3 = new OleDbParameter();
        p4 = new OleDbParameter();
        p5 = new OleDbParameter();

         cn.Open();

        p1.ParameterName = "O_Name";
        p1.Value = TextBox1.Text;

        p2.ParameterName = "O_Add";
        p2.Value = TextBox2.Text;

        p3.ParameterName = "E_Mail";
        p3.Value = TextBox3.Text;

        p4.ParameterName = "Mob";
        p4.Value = Double.Parse(TextBox4.Text);

        p5.ParameterName = "password";
        p5.Value = TextBox5.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into user values (@O_Name,@O_Add,@E_Mail,@Mob,@password)";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
      }
}
```

Comment: please share the values of p1,p2,p3 ... p5 and the user table structure

Comment: Please also give the error message. One thing I would try is specifying the names of the columns that you're inserting into: `insert into user (col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, col_name4, col_name5) values (@O_Name, ...)`

Comment: Seems that your INSERT statement doesn't include column names - try adding column names as @Skippy suggests. One more thing: one of the field names potentially messing up since it may conflicted with certain Access keyword, ensure using square brackets (`[` and `]`) around them.